# Continous map question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous s.t. $f(0)=f(1)$.

Let $$ A = \{ (t,s)\in [0,1] \times [0,1]|: t \neq s\,\,\, \rm and \,\,\, \ f(t)=f(s)\},$$

then find the number of elements in $A$.

Comment: Not really a general topology question.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not constant, it has a maximal or a minimal value somewhere in $x'=(0,1)$. Use the intermediate value theorem to show that every value between $f(x')$ and $f(0)$ is achieved twice, from both sides of $x'$.